# Python: Why does the position of each element change when using for loop for with float()

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

My code:

```
from math import sqrt

nums = {float(sqrt(x)) for x in range(0, 10)}
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
{0.0, 1.0, 
 2.0, 1.7320508075688772, 
 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 
 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 
 2.8284271247461903, 3.0}
```

Why does the position of each element change when using `float(sqrt(x))`?

Comment: Please post your code inline, as text; do not make required information only available from off-site resources, particularly not as images.

Comment: - My code: from math import sqrt
nums = {float(sqrt(x)) for x in range(0, 10)}
print(nums)
- Output: {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.7320508075688772, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903, 3.0}

Comment: Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @ThànhLongNguyễn: Edit it into your question, comments are terrible for formatted code.

Comment: You dont even need float() there

Comment: I have edited. I sincerely apologize for being the first time I posted a question. T_T

Comment: Since its a dict comprehension you probably are looking for something like `num = {x:sqrt(x) for x in range(10)}` notice there is no need to set starting point of range as `0` as its already set by default.

Comment: @Mick_ If i haven't float() then the results are the same

Comment: @Mick_ The results are printed in the right place :D

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @Mick_ I don't understand why position of each element be change when using float(sqrt(x)) :)) thanks for your support!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using `set` type (curly braces - `{}`) to store your results, and this type is **unordered**, like `dict`.

Use `list` (square brackets - `[]`) instead:

```
from math import sqrt

nums = [float(sqrt(x)) for x in range(0, 10)]
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 
1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 
2.0, 2.23606797749979, 
2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 
2.8284271247461903, 3.0]
```